# Iterate Array 30 times using For loop

Tags: arrays, swift

I have an Array with 8 elements I want to copy the  elements one by one until the count of new array reach 30 times.

I used for loop and while the result was copying only the first element 30 times.

```
    let myShift = ["D12","E","N12","N","Off","Rest1","Rest2","D"]
var myArray = [String]()
for i in myShift {
while myArray.count != 30 {
    myArray.append(i)   
}}
```

I read some examples about map I tried to use it but it didn't work.

Comment: You want to copy each element 30 times ? Is that it ? I am sorry, I do not understand exactly what you mean. Please precise.

Comment: That's 8 elements...

Comment: I want to copy all element one by one until the count of new array reached 30.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since it's not very clear what you are looking for, here are two options.

This one will repeat the contents of the array until it reaches 30 items in total. It will keep their order and loop them. This results in an array with 30 elements.

```
let myShift = ["D12","E","N12","N","Off","Rest1","Rest2","D"]
var myArray = [String]()
(0..<30).forEach {
  myArray.append(myShift[$0 % myShift.count])
}
```

This one will result in an array with each element repeated 30 times, with a total of 240 elements.

```
let myShift = ["D12","E","N12","N","Off","Rest1","Rest2","D"]
let array = [[String]](count: 30, repeatedValue: myShift).flatMap { $0 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
    let myShift = ["D12","E","N12","N","Off","Rest1","Rest2","D"]
    var myArray = [Array]()
    while myArray.count < 31 {
        myArray.append(myShift)   
    }}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this:

```
let myShift = ["D12","E","N12","N","Off","Rest1","Rest2","D"]
var myArray = [String]()

for i in myShift {
    myArray.appendContentsOf(Array(count: 30, repeatedValue: i))
}
```

Answer (score 0):

So, rather than using a `while` and a `for` loop, I like to use a good old double `for`-loop.
The following code produces an array with 240 items (8*30=240).

```
let myShift = ["D12","E","N12","N","Off","Rest1","Rest2","D"]
var newArray = myShift

for i in 1...30 {
    for str in myShift {
        newArray.append(str)
    }
}
```

Playground approves:
[image: playground]

Hope this helps :)